# Center SECTION set as inline block?

Tags: html, css

I have a section defined like this:

```
<footer>
    <section id="content">
        <section id="footer-links" class="center">
            <a href="index.php" class="float-left">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="float-left">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="float-left">Contact</a>
            <a href="terms.html" class="float-left">Terms and Conditions</a>
        </section>
    </section>
</footer>
```

And I've applied the following CSS:

### footer

```
background-color: 
rgb(53, 53, 181);
color: 
rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
height: 100px;
width: 1424px;
```

### section (#content)

```
background-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: 
rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
height: 19px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 312px;
margin-right: 312px;
margin-top: 0px;
position: relative;
width: 800px;
```

### section (#footer-links)

```
background-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: 
rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
height: 19px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 332px;
```

### a

```
background-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-color: 
rgb(222, 222, 222);
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
color: 
rgb(222, 222, 222);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
height: 18px;
margin-right: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 39px;
```

[image: Footer Left Aligned]

But, as you can see, it left aligned the `section`. Hopefully you all can help!

Comment: Which `section`? There's two. Why not just `text-align: center`? Not sure what `display: inline-block` is trying to solve here.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I would like to center the section with the links, `footer-links`, and the idea behind `inline-block` was that I thought the `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` that I applied would cause it to center.

Comment: You just a width on the parent element. Here's what you posted (not fixed): http://jsfiddle.net/3Kk2L/

Comment: I've tweaked and removed some properties (like the `float` and widths) for demonstration purposes, but check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/3Kk2L/1/

Comment: I think this might be a little closer to what you're looking for (and condensed): http://jsfiddle.net/3Kk2L/3/ Note the `html, body ` part at top, which gives me a `width` to work with on the `footer`, and the use of `nav` instead of another `section`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, perfect! Post that last Fiddle as an answer and it will be yours my friend! Thanks a lot!

Comment: First we had div-itis and now HTML5 has given us section-itis.

Comment: @Rob - Yeah, semantics. I remember when DIVS WERE BAAAD and layers gave folks convulsions. Plaintext everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular use of `display: inline-block` is probably not what you're after (and I think the `float: left` part is also probably the wrong approach. For instance:

```
<footer>
    <section id="content">
        <nav id="footer-links" class="center">   
            <a href="index.php" class="float-left">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="float-left">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html" class="float-left">Contact</a>
            <a href="terms.html" class="float-left">Terms and Conditions</a>
        </nav>
    </section>
</footer>​
```

Note the use of `nav` instead of a second `section` (semantically). Next, I'll clean up and address the issue of "centering" the links by centering the `nav` using `margin: 0 auto`. You need a `width` on both the parent `#content` *and* the `nav`:

```
html, /* This part allows me to set margin: 0 auto; on footer. */
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
footer {
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 181);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px; /* Note this line. */
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Note this line. */
}
#content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 600px; /* The same width as footer. Keep that in mind. */
}
#footer-links {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 19px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px; /* 200px less than #content and footer */
    text-align: center; /* HINT! This actually centers the text. */
    font-size: 16px;
}
#footer-links a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(222, 222, 222);
    color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
    cursor: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block; /* So the next line will work.  */
    margin: 0 8px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Kk2L/3/

Now, the `text-align: center` on `#footer-links a` *actually centers the content*. That's important to observe here.

*Also note* I *do* use `display: inline-block` within on `#footer-links a`, which then allows me to set a defined `margin` and not inherit the `1px dotted` underline on the gaps. *However*, IE7 and lower do not support `display: inline-block` and you should check first if that's required what it does look like. Personally, I would worry about it too much, unless you really need to support IE7 and (*cringe*) IE6.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can eliminate all of those ids/classes, and just target the elements with `inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/qwM6z/